# H2 in-memory database initialization with data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, h2

I'm using H2 with Hibernate to generate in-memory DB on the fly for unit-testing.
I managed to create the DB successfully, and everything is working ok.
But I have an issue I don't know how to approach.
I need to load reference data to the DB for testing prior to the execution of the tests.
I have this data sored as a SQL insert's file which I need to run only once in real time envirnemnt, however, because the DB is generated every time from scratch I need to figure out how to insert the data on runtime.
The data is quite simple, it's countries lists, states list, etc.
Whats the best way to do it ?

btw, everything is working underneath Spring framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your tests you could execute an init script on creation of the connection.

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, but I have a persistent DB of ~300MB, with many indexes. Converting it to SQL statments and initialising them will be very slow. Is there a way to initialise from the binary DB itself?

Comment: @HRJ Internally we are using a hsqldb db saved in a jar file. However I didn't test it with such a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

From the question tags I see you're using Hibernate. You can add a file named "import.sql" to your classpath (i.e. in src/main/resources if you're using a Maven project layout).

[From Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

> In addition, a file named import.sql in the root of the classpath will
>   be executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch
>   (that is if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop).
>   This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful, but
>   probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production.
>   It is a Hibernate feature (nothing to do with Spring).

Comment: And since some people might now know about it, if you don't already have the "console" H2 endpoint to manage the database, you can add the property `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` to your .properties (or .yml) file and you will be able to access the endpoint "h2-console". For the in-memory database, you have to change the "JDBC URL" to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`. No password is required, just click on "connect". I'm writing this because I found this useful to see the structure of the database when my initialization queries were failing.

Comment: P.S.: I suggest to read that documentation and not stop just at this answer. For example, I actually needed to name the file "data.sql" and not "import.sql".